# Does iOS CalDAV and CardDAV support non-default ports?

Tags: ios, port, caldav, carddav

I am trying to connect to CalDAV server from iPad, iOS v7.0.2(11A501), that is running on HTTP port 8080. It failed to connect.

Using Fiddler tool I have found that iPad CalDAV client is sending requests to port 443 and to port 80 instead of the one I specify in 'Server' field.

Being able to run the server on port 80 only in the development environment is inconvenient.

Has anybody experienced this issue and are there are any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Well, my iPad is setup to a Mavericks calendar server. Which is running on https://xxx.local:8443/.

So the answer to your question seems to be Yes. It does support non-standard SSL ports. (This is on iOS 7.0.5/6).

What configuration data do you provide to iOS? Could it be that it initially connects to the right port but then the server is somehow misconfigured and redirects the client to a standard port?
Which CalDAV server do you use?